# Has this happened to anyone else in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Right to the point. My visual studio being connected to Github has been working perfectly until now.
I entered a new project, finished it, went to go into Team Explorer and all that was there was just the settings tab and beneath it saying "Git features have moved, tools and controls for Git source have moved to their own tool window.
I could not find a single answer to this question and my professor is kinda baffled himself.
Anyone know what Could have potentially happened that it would just move itself into a source i cannot even find??

Comment: There should be an "Open Git Changes" link right under that message. That goes to the new tool window it mentions. Do you not have that?

Comment: You will also notice under the `View` menu, there are few new git windows. Personally i think the new regime is better in some ways, but clunky and a bit meh in others

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft released the latest version of Visual Studio with some changes to Team Explorer. Git has been moved to the new location but you can revert that to go back to looking like it used to,

Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features
Scroll down towards the bottom to find "New Git user experience". Uncheck that and you'll find your team explorer back to the way it was.

Comment: Holy shit... Thank you so much! highly appreciated! You win at life this night, and happy Thanksgiving!